# How old was King Rastakhan at the time of Battle for Azeroth?

Tags: warcraft

In the [WoW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Warcraft) expansion "[**Battle for Azeroth**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Warcraft%3A_Battle_for_Azeroth)", players finally visit the legendary Zandalari Empire. Horde players meet its king, Rastakhan, eventually even

> saving his life after a coup by his advisers.

During the quest to do so, players witness the following exchange between Rezan (Loa of Kings) and Bwonsamdi (Loa of Death):

> **Rezan:** The Little King will rise. I am not finished with him. Bwonsamdi!
>
> **Bwonsamdi:** Ya got a bellow dat would wake da dead! What ya want, mon?
>
> **Rezan:** You have taken what is mine. Release him.
>
> **Bwonsamdi:** Long time, ya been keepin' dis one from me. Long, long time. I'll be denied no further.
>
> **Rezan:** Know your place, loa of graves, or I will put you in one.
>
> **Bwonsamdi:** Comes a time when we all gotta die... even kings.

This conversation seems to imply that Rastakhan is much older than other trolls, which typically have a lifespan comparable to that of humans & orcs. Or perhaps that he has escaped death on multiple occasions. Howeverm the "long, long time" bit leads me to think that his lifespan has been unnaturally prolonged by Rezan.

**How old was King Rastakhan at the time of Battle for Azeroth?**

*Note: I am asking here instead of Arqade SE because this is more about the game lore than gameplay or mechanics.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the lore object "[For Council and King](https://wow.gamepedia.com/For_Council_and_King)", found on the Isle of Thunder,

> From a golden throne, lording over all of the Zandalari, rests the great King Rastakhan.
>
> Empowered by the Zandalari gods themselves to act as their voice, he has ruled for over two hundred years.

Although his exact age is unclear, it's at least two hundred years and probably a fair bit more (assuming that he didn't take the throne until he was an adult). There aren't many references that I can find to the typical troll lifespan, but it doesn't seem to be that long, giving weight to the idea that Rezan has unnaturally extended Rastakhan's life.